# Native Android UI Component not updating

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native

I'm having issues with a Native UI Component that is used in React-Native. The situation is that I have an existing, functioning, completed layout in Android that I need to reuse in a react-native view.

The existing layout (in Android):

- has a loading-layout
- has a RecyclerView
- does api-calls while showing the loading-layout
- once done it updates the RecyclerView and hides the loading-layout
- works perfectly in a native environment.

To expose this existing layout and use it in React-Native I did as told
by the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html). Exposing properties, callbacks or events was not required as the existing layout is closed and works as is.

The React-Native view:

- is a simple view
- that imports the existing layout as described by the docs
- actually shows the initial loading-layout of the existing layout

The problem occurs when the data is loaded. With debugging you can see that the code is run to update the layout, but that is visually not shown. **The loading-layout keeps showing, until you perform a scroll-gesture which redraws the screen and shows the RecyclerView with the loaded data.** As if the RecyclerView was already there but just not showing.

Would anybody know what could be the problem?

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2):

try adding this function, and change base_svg to the iew that you disered :

```
private final Runnable measureAndLayout = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            base_svg.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(base_svg.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(base_svg.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            base_svg.layout(base_svg.getLeft(), base_svg.getTop(), base_svg.getRight(), base_svg.getBottom());
        }
    };
```

After you add the new information to the screen call that function this way:

```
    base_svg.post(measureAndLayout);
```

Check if it renders the new views that you add or remove.

To be honest I don't know the reason why. but this work for me. I think react is forcing you to just to render when react wants.
Check this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11829) for more understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Flavio_Lima!! for a more generic solution you can look at this https://github.com/tlcheah2/test/commit/9a70c2b985769a2a8277219d104b0893b406eb49

Comment: you saved my life. Thank you very much